# tikz and pdf: label rotation leads to overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, pgfplotstable, rotating

As can be seen in the below example, I'm trying to create a confusion matrix via tikzpicture (haven't found any nice solutions via table that allows for easy color grading). However, due to the limited space, the rotation of the tickslabels leads to an overlap between them. I guess this is a result of a centered rotation point. Does anyone here have a fix for this issue that still allows for the specified rotation angles? In the best case scenario the last letter of each ticklabel should end at the axis tick marker regardless of the specified rotation.

[image: Minimal example with label overlap]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\newcommand{\abe}{abe}
\newcommand{\abee}{abeeeeeeeeee}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.5\textwidth,
height=0.5\textwidth,
scale only axis,
axis on top,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=14.5,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
xticklabels={{\abe},{\abee},\abe},
xticklabel style={rotate=40},
xlabel={Predicted Class},
xlabel near ticks,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=0.5,
ymax=14.5,
ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
yticklabel style={rotate=40},
ylabel={True Class},
ylabel near ticks,
ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You need to define anchors of tick labels. For example:

```
xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=north east},`
```

and

```
yticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=south east},
```

Then you will get the following result:

[image]

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I was looking for!